# Getting an error when hosting my nextjs application on CENTOS WEB PANEL using custom server

Tags: express, next.js, hosting

I'm trying to host a nextjs application on CENTOS WEB PANEL, im using a custom server (server.js file) just as outlined on next docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/custom-server. My problem is that a simple express node js application which is using express server is running smoothly but when i try setting up next js app, the app is not running at all.

When i host a normal node js application with a start up file of index.js using express, the application starts to run successfully. but when i try hosting a nextjs application im getting this error: [Thu Mar 14 14:56:24.728686 2024] [proxy_http:error] [pid 70656:tid 140403621721856] [client xx.xx.xx.xx:51110] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1, referer: https://roofa.co.ke/

**here is my custom server(server.js file): **

```
const { createServer } = require('http')
const { parse } = require('url')
const next = require('next')
 
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const hostname = 'localhost'
const port = 3000
// when using middleware `hostname` and `port` must be provided below
const app = next({ dev, hostname, port })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()
 
app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer(async (req, res) => {
    try {
      // Be sure to pass `true` as the second argument to `url.parse`.
      // This tells it to parse the query portion of the URL.
      const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
      const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl
 
if (pathname === '/a') {
        await app.render(req, res, '/a', query)
      } else if (pathname === '/b') {
        await app.render(req, res, '/b', query)
      } else {
        await handle(req, res, parsedUrl)
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error occurred handling', req.url, err)
      res.statusCode = 500
      res.end('internal server error')
    }
  })
    .once('error', (err) => {
      console.error(err)
      process.exit(1)
    })
    .listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`> Ready on http://${hostname}:${port}`)
    })
})
```

Comment: please do help me